# Spring boot dependency injection of an interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I have 2 spring boot microservice let's say core and persistence. where persistence has a dependency on core.

I have defined an interface in core whose implementation is inside persistence as below:

**core**

```java
package com.mine.service;
public interface MyDaoService {
}
```

**Persistence**

```java
package com.mine.service.impl;
@Service
public class MyDaoServiceImpl implements MyDaoService {
}
```

I am trying to inject MyDaoService in another service which is in core only:

**core**

```java
package com.mine.service;
@Service
public class MyService {

private final MyDaoService myDaoService;

    public MyService(MyDaoService myDaoService) {
        this.myDaoService = myDaoService;
    }
}
```

while doing this i am getting this weird error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.mine.service.MyService required a bean of type 'com.mine.service.MyDaoService' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.mine.service.MyDaoService' in your configuration.
```

can anyone explain me why ?

NOTE: i have already included com.mine.service in componentscan of springbootapplication as below

```java
package com.mine.restpi;
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mine")
public class MyRestApiApplication {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyRestApiApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is MyDaoService configured as a bean?  It cannot be injected if it's not configured as a bean. This can be done through annotation or configuration

Comment: Can you add your project structure (i.e. packages, classes etc.)?

Comment: also your poms. There should be mutual dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `@Service` annotation to your impl classes and the `@Autowired` annotation to the constructor.

```
// Include the @Service annotation
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

}

// Include the @Service annotation and @Autowired annotation on the constructor
@Service
public class MyDaoServiceImpl implements MyDaoService {

    private final MyService myService ;

    @Autowired
    public MyDaoServiceImpl(MyService myService){
       this.myService = myService;
    }
}
```

Comment: As of Spring 4.3 the `@Autowired` isn't needed anymore when you have a single constructor.

Comment: Implementation classes are already annotated with `@Service`. 

I tried adding `@Autowired` at constrcutor level. but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the error message hint: *Consider defining a bean of type 'com.mine.service.MyDaoService' in your configuration*  to solve this problem you can define in your package `com.mine` a configuration class named `MyConfiguration` annotated with [`@Configuration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) including a bean named myDaoService like below:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public MyDaoService myDaoService() {
        return new MyDaoServiceImpl();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, move `MyRestApiApplication` class to `com.mine` package and remove `@ComponentScan` annotation.

```
package com.mine;
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class MyRestApiApplication {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyRestApiApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```